# alias name should be same or not for updating app in android market?

Tags: android

i had launched one app in android market and now i going to release next version.
i came to know that for updating the app i want to use same keystore and same password.
now i getting doubt about my alias name . 
which one is better for updating my application in android market , whether i have to use same alias name or different alias name.
If i used different alias name application will get update or not.
2) is it possible change the password for my private keystore.
can any one explain about the steps to change the password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most importantly, be VERY careful with your keystore!!  You can only update your app with a new version that has been signed with the same keystore.  I have known more than one person (myself included) who has lost or corrupted their keystore and had to upload a whole new app with a different app identifier and try to get all of their users to go get that app instead!  It's an extreme hassel!

As for the "alias" do you mean the name that is displayed under the icon on the device?  If so you can change that whenever you want.  The Play Store uses the package identifier (com.google.etc) to identify your app so as long as you leave that the same it will know which app it is.